# How to take data from native storage, add to an array then add back to native storage

Tags: android, arrays, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am building an app using ionic/cordova. I need to be able to scan a barcode, then add a timestamp (achieved this) to the devices native storage.

I tried just adding scan data to the native storage, but found that it just overwrites existing scan data. I then tried this using an array, but again noticed if I change page, when the page loads again the array is empty, so that it replaces existing data with the new empty array.

What I "think" I need to do is -
Create an empty array
Take existing data native storage and add to this array
Add new scan data to this array
Then add the array back to native storage.

What I am currently stuck on is taking the data out of native storage and adding to an array.
My code is -

```
export class ScanSession {

scans: any [];

constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner, private          
nativeStorage: NativeStorage) { 
 this.scans = [];   
}

ScanCode() : any{
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {

this.nativeStorage.getItem('scans')
.then(
  data => console.log(data),
  error => console.error(error)
);

  this.scans.push(data);

let inputString = "testData";

//let ts = new Date();

if( barcodeData.text == inputString){
  //this.scans.push(ts);
  this.nativeStorage.setItem('scans', (JSON.stringify(this.scans)))
  //(JSON.stringify(this.scans)
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
  //console.log("Success");
  //console.log(this.scans);

  //this.nativeStorage.getItem('scans')
  //.then(
  //  data => console.log(data),
  //  error => console.error(error)
  // );

} else {
  console.log("Doesnt Match");
}

}, (err) => {

});
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing JSON.parse as your using JSON.stringify, you need to unstringify, if you get what i mean.

Change

```
 this.nativeStorage.getItem('scans')
```

To

```
 JSON.parse(this.nativeStorage.getItem('scans'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns an error when I just make the change.
Have I got my code right elsewhere? I'm unsure where in the code I should be using the getItem command.

Comment: try adding it to a var first like so: var myData= JSON.parse(this.nativeStorage.getItem('scans')); what's in the var ?, NB: with a corodva app you can use localStorage without the extra layer.

Comment: also localstoage is not async the promise will resolve straight away so no need to use then, strictly speaking see https://www.peterbe.com/plog/localstorage-is-fast

Comment: I tried - 
    var myData = JSON.parse(this.nativeStorage.getItem('scans');)
Returns an error saying - Arguement of type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: try it without the then function and try with localStorage instead if nativeSrorage try both combos.

Comment: I'm getting myself quite muddled up now.

Ive changed the code to create the array OUTSIDE of the ScanCode(), as I realized that each time the function is called its creating a new array.

However I still cant find a way to retrieve current data in native storage, add to an array, add something, add back to native storage.

Also I tried - 
console.log(nativeStorage);
Returns -
_super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;

So I think my data isnt even being pushed to native storage correctly.